# Force user to choose only one selector 'a href' using Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

Ive working on a short piece of code to generate a media tag search, but I'm a little stuck on something.

```
 ($("#interiors_search a").click(function(event) {)
```

What I need to do and for the life of me, cant figure out how, is, on the first column, which is room type only allow the user to select one choice.

As you can see, clicking a selection uses onclick to update the tag array using jQuery, then on submit, the tag array is sent to the results page.

So it must add the selection to the array and also, if user changes mind, remove the previous selected tag from the array whilst only allowing one choice.

At the moment all works and multiple tag selection is good, but I dont want to rely on the user using their brain to only check one room type as if two or more room types are selected it will return an empty query.

Any help is as always much appreciated.

Here is the fiddle to what I have so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/z1s18dwa/1/

JS

```
 Propertywise = {};

 Propertywise = {
   filters: function() {
     if (jQuery(".interiors_filter").is(":visible")) {
       jQuery('.interiors_filter').stop().slideUp('fast');
     } else {
       jQuery('.interiors_filter').stop().slideDown();
     }
   },
   tags: {}
 }

 $("#interiors_search a").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var tag = $(this).data('value');
   $(this).toggleClass("selected");

   if (Propertywise.tags[tag]) {
     delete Propertywise.tags[tag];

   } else {
     Propertywise.tags[tag] = true;

   }

 });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="interiors">
   <div id="content" class="content sub_holder">
     <div class="fullbleed">
       <ul class="menu" id="interiors_menu">
         <li id="interiors_menu_search">
           <a href="#" onclick="Propertywise.filters(); return false;">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown" href="#" onclick="Propertywise.filters(); return false;">Search by room</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown" href="#" onclick="Propertywise.filters(); return false;">Search by style</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown" href="#" onclick="Propertywise.filters(); return false;">Search by colour</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown" href="#" onclick="Propertywise.filters(); return false;">Search by feature</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="interiors_filter tags columns_4" style="display: block;">
    <form id="interiors_search" name="interiors_search">
      <ol class="details">
        <li>
          <h3>Rooms</h3>
          <p><a data-value="bathroom" href="#">Bathroom</a>
            <a data-value="bedroom" href="#">Bedroom</a>
            <a data-value="kitchen" href="#">Kitchen</a>
            <a data-value="outside-space" href="#">Outside space</a>
            <a data-value="reception" href="#">Reception</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Styles</h3>
          <p><a data-value="contemporary" href="#">Contemporary</a>
            <a data-value="country" href="#">Country</a>
            <a data-value="quirky" href="#">Quirky</a>
            <a data-value="traditional" href="#">Traditional</a></p>
        </li>
        <li id="d3">
          <h3>Colours</h3>
          <p><a data-value="black" href="#">Black</a>
            <a data-value="blue" href="#">Blue</a>
            <a data-value="brown" href="#">Brown</a>
            <a data-value="colourful" href="#">Colourful</a>
            <a data-value="cream" href="#">Cream</a>
            <a data-value="green" href="#">Green</a>
            <a data-value="grey" href="#">Grey</a>
            <a data-value="pink" href="#">Pink</a>
            <a data-value="red" href="#">Red</a>
            <a data-value="white" href="#">White</a>
            <a data-value="yellow" href="#">Yellow</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Features</h3>
          <p><a data-value="childrens" href="#">Children's</a>
                <a data-value="feature-fireplace" href="#">Feature fireplace</a>
                <a data-value="feature-lighting" href="#">Feature lighting</a>
                <a data-value="feature-staircase" href="#">Feature staircase</a>
                <a data-value="great-view" href="#">Great View</a>
                <a data-value="home-office" href="#">Home Office</a>
                <a data-value="hotel-chic" href="#">Hotel chic</a>
                <a data-value="loft-living" href="#">Loft living</a>
                <a data-value="open-plan" href="#">Open-plan</a>
                <a data-value="outdoor-living" href="#">Outdoor living</a>
                <a data-value="small" href="#">Small</a>
                <a data-value="statement-bath" href="#">Statement bath</a>
                <a data-value="statement-wallpaper" href="#">Statement wallpaper</a>
                <a data-value="swimming-pool" href="#">Swimming pool</a></p>
            </li>
          </ol>
          <p class="cta"></p>
          <input class="submit" style="cursor:pointer;font-size:130%;clear:both;margin:24px auto;float:none;display:block;border:none;text-transform:uppercase;background-color:#fff000;" type="button" value="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a working snippet here that I wrote up real quick, there's lots of ways to handle it but this works well enough.

I added a class to the paragraph wrapping the anchor tags for the room:

```
<p class='rooms'>
```

I use that class in the click event to force the user to only have one row selected with this code:

```
  if ($(this).closest('p').hasClass('rooms')) {
      $(this).closest('p').find('a').each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('selected');
      });
  }
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z1s18dwa/4/

**EDIT**

I added some code to handle the tags, when I remove the 'selected' class I just remove the tags as well.

```
  var roomTag = $(this).data('value');
  if (Propertywise.tags[roomTag]) {
        delete Propertywise.tags[roomTag];
  }
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z1s18dwa/13/

Comment: Hi,Yes, works perfectly for de-selection of the link, unfortunately this doesnt update (or) remover the tag from the array which is where I am stuck, adding the remove/add into the deselection.

Basically, the class is just a css selector and doesnt bear any relevence on the form input..

Comment: While got your attention :)D

Was thinking here while trying to figure out, would be good to have the previously selected tags remain selected after search submit..

Would you add Jquery to hightlight the selectors or use php $_GET?

Comment: It depends on the submit.  If the page refreshes, than you'd have to either cache the selection or load it from where it was saved.  Loading it from a saved location would most likely be php.  If you use an Ajax request everything could be handled in jQuery.